# Phoenix/Elixir - timestamps does not exist, expanding to timestamps()

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am learning Phoenix using the book 'Programming Phoenix'. The first project has creating a postgres db and this is our migration. I cannot get rid of a warning for timestamps in my schema.

```
defmodule Rumbl.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string
      add :username, :string, null: false
      add :password_hash, :string

      timestamps
    end

    create unique_index(:users, [:username])
  end
end
```

Then our model corresponding to this migration is:

```
defmodule Rumbl.User do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string

    timestamps
  end
end
```

Now I run the migration, followed by `mix phoenix.server`.

And I get this warning:

```
warning: variable "timestamps" does not exist and is being expanded to "timestamps()", 
please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
web/models/user.ex:10
```

If I change `timestamps` in the schema to `timestamps()` it doesn't complain, anymore, but the book never shows what the model's schema looks like after running the migration. Is that supposed to be right, or is there something else that fixes that? What is the 'timestamps' representation in an Ecto/Phoenix schema supposed to look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elixir 1.4 added a warning on calling an imported or locally defined function with 0 arguments without a parentheses, as it is ambiguous on what it should mean when you have a local variable with the same name as the function and you write the variable name without parentheses.

> [Kernel] Warn if variable is used as a function call

[Source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4/CHANGELOG.md#elixir-4)

The book probably hasn't been updated for Elixir 1.4 yet. Phoenix generators were updated to add the parentheses [in June 2016](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/b9e4ae9f658108d1def9a32c27b06c318ae67a98).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's good to know what was going on, because my google searches were not helping.